# loops and arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have some php that hits a website. scrapes it for an item and then a price. i am having trouble joining them so i get

```
item 1 price 1
item 2 price 2
```

what i am getting is

```
item 1 price 1
item 1 price 2
item 1 price 3
item 2 price 1
item 2 price 2
item 2 price 3
```

here is my code

```
foreach($matches[0] as $item){
    foreach ($matchprice[0] as $pricevalue)    {    
        echo '<span style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 12pt;';
        echo $item;
        echo $pricevalue;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

I have tried moving the items in and around the loops and using counts and even tried merging the arrays. All i got was array array as an out put. I hope i have made this clear enough.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you get the data of the array? from a database? if so, you can filter the data with a LEFT JOIN, then you get only the data you really wish to show up and not everything in your tables, but I'm not sure about your question, please provide some more details.

Comment: The code you've provided in your question is incomplete which makes it very hard to decipher your question.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that `$matches` and `$matchprice` are populated from the same database.

```
foreach($matches[0] as $i => $item)
    echo '<span style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 12pt;>' . $item . ' - ' . $matchprice[0][$i] . '</span><br />';
```

I also feel that this code could be much improved with a different over all approach and you should look at the whole thing. Something like the following would be ideal.

```
foreach($items as $item)
    echo "<span style=\"item\">{$item['name']} - {$item['price']}</span><br />";
```

If your getting this information from an SQL database, you should be able to modify your query to make this easily possibly with most table setups.

Answer (score 0):

use a simple for loop, like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
  echo '<span>', $matches[0][$i], ", ", $matchprice[0][$i], '</span/>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have an if statement in the for loop to match the item with the price .

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pointed in the right direction, even if it's not *exactly* what you're looking for.

```
$itemIndex = 0;
foreach($matches[0] as $item){
    $innerLoopItemIndex = 0;
    foreach ($matchprice[0] as $pricevalue)    {    
        if($innerLoopItemIndex++ < $itemIndex) continue;

        echo '<span style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 12pt;';
        echo $item;
        echo $pricevalue;
        echo "<br />";
    }
    $itemIndex += 1;
}
```